# Configure API Management security token to the same as used in the React app's SSO

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-entra-id

I have an Azure Entra AD auth setup on my React app.

I want to configure my API Management to authenticate using the same JWT.

I have searched online for multiple options but they all involve setting up another Entra app. Then getting a new JWT from Developer Portal sign in process.

Is it possible to do what I am looking for?

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.